# MVC6: Dependency Injection into EF7 Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to use DI to inject an instance of a class that does encryption/decryption into ApplicationUser, a class used to hold user information in an MVC6 app. But I'm missing something, as it's not working.

The ApplicationUser class looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [FromServices]
    [NotMapped]
    public StringCrypt Crypt { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string SiteID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string SitePassword {
        get
        {
            bool requiresMigration = false;
            bool wasRevoked = false;

            return Crypt.Unprotect(SitePW, out requiresMigration, out wasRevoked);
        }

        set { SitePW = Crypt.Protect(value); }
    }

    protected string SitePW { get; set; }
}
```

This is intended to support a situation where the password to a third party site is stored, in encrypted form, in the database, but is accessible transparently in its decrypted form.

The StringCrypt class relies on the built-in ASPNET6 data protection API:

```
public class StringCrypt : IStringCrypt
{
    private IPersistedDataProtector _dp;

    public StringCrypt( IDataProtectionProvider dpProvider )
    {
        _dp = (IPersistedDataProtector) dpProvider.CreateProtector("passwords");
    }

    public string Unprotect( string protectedData, out bool requiresMigration, out bool wasRevoked )
    {
        bool ignoreRevocation = true;

        byte[] protectedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(protectedData);
        byte[] unprotectedBytes = _dp.DangerousUnprotect(protectedBytes, ignoreRevocation, out requiresMigration, out wasRevoked);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unprotectedBytes);
    }

    public string Protect( string clearText )
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);
        byte[] protectedBytes = _dp.Protect(clearBytes);

        string result = Convert.ToBase64String(protectedBytes);

        return result;
    }
}
```

My attempt to glue this all together with the built-in dependency injection system requires a few tweaks to the ConfigureServices method in startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        // normal stuff created by VS2015...

        services.AddDataProtection();

        // have to avoid setting a file path when we're invoked by dnx
        // HostEnvironment is an instance of IHostingEnvironment, set in
        // the constructor for Startup
        if( (HostEnvironment != null) && (HostEnvironment.WebRootPath != null ) )
            services.ConfigureDataProtection(configure =>
            {
                string pathToCryptoKeys = Path.Combine(HostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "dp_keys");
                configure.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(pathToCryptoKeys));
                configure.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.MaxValue);
            });

        services.AddTransient<StringCrypt>();
    }
```

But when I run the site, and I get to the Crypt.Protect() call in ApplicationUser, it fails because the Crypt property -- which should be an instance of StringCrypt -- is undefined. Which means it was never set...which is what I thought tagging it with [FromServices] would do.

Are instances of ApplicationUser created in some way which bypasses the DI system? Or does [FromServices] not work outside of controllers or views?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/115 also https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3578

Comment: Thanx! I missed that.